# How do I migrate my iTunes media library from Windows PC to Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, itunes, migration

How do I migrate my iTunes media library from my old laptop with windows (all music stored on external hard drive), to my new MacBook without losing any files and data, i.e. playcounts, ratings, playlists etc?

Answer (score 2):

See [Migrate Your iTunes Library from Windows to Mac (and keep your ratings, play counts and date added)](http://www.tunequest.org/migrating-your-itunes-library-from-windows-to-mac/20061105/).